# Is it acceptable to append information to word embeddings?

Tags: word2vec, nlp, vector-space-models

Let's say I have my 300 dimensional word embedding trained with Word2Vec and it contains 10,000 word vectors.

I have additional data on the 10,000 words in the form of a vector (10,000x1), containing values between 0 and 1. Can I simply append the vector to the word embedding so that I have a 301 dimensional embedding?

I am looking to calculate similarities between word vectors using cosine similarity.

Comment: IMO it depends on how and where you are going to use that, both outcomes are plausible better results, worse results

Comment: I'm just using it to compare two words. I gather from your comment that it may work if the additional column is correlated with the existing embeddings.

Comment: No it may be uncorrelated and work just fne, it just depends on where and how this extra attached information is going to be used, as such it is an open-ended question

Comment: It is going to be used in a similarity function implementing the cosine similarity.

Comment: it is hard to say, systematic trial and error is what makes science